# Clarify TFVC Folder and Branch approach for initial SQL Solution

Tags: tfs, version-control, branch, azure-devops, tfvc

Previously our department has not had source control for our SQL-Server based internal Database applications (so sql scripts not .net code).

Visual Studio 2013

Team Foundation Server 2012

SQL Server 2012

We are now introducing TFVC to our small department but I am unsure of how to initially define the internal TFS folder-structure necessary to support our expected version control usage. And how that fits with the Branching strategy.

Our expectation is that we'll be using standard mainline branching strategy. i.e. **Development**, **UAT** and **Production** versions of the codebase.

So, when initial development of *OurApp01* is ready for UAT, our Main codebase will be Branched to create a Dev codebase upon which development of *OurApp02* will continue. UAT and any required fixes will be applied to the Main codebase. When UAT is complete and *OurApp01* is moved into Production, another Branch will be created for our Production codebase. At this point, the Main codebase will also be merged back into the Development codebase to ensure that fixes made during UAT are present within Development.

My assumption is that we only have a single Main folder structure within TFS, reflected locally. Then after we create the Dev and Prod Branches, we can create **Local** folders for the source associated with these Branches. But we do *not*  create /Dev or /Prod folders in TFS - we still have just the one /Main folder, but it has two Branches for Dev and Prod.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branches will look like folders in TFS, and on your file system. This is how branches are represented in TFS, effectively they are separate folders that also have a branching relationship.

You'll have a structure that looks something like this

`$TeamProject/Main
             /Dev
             /Production`

Your local file system will probably look very similar, depending on how you map your workspace.

One word of caution, TFS VC enforces a strict branching hierarchy and merging outside of this can be painful.

[The ALM Rangers Version Control guidance](https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) is well worth a read